# PropertyChangedTrigger doesn't work - wrong namespace?

Tags: silverlight, triggers, expression-blend

I put the following (via Expression Blend 4) in my XAML file:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <ei:DataStoreChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusMessage}">
   <ei:ControlStoryboardAction/>
   </ei:DataStoreChangedTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When building the project, Expression Blend throws following error:

> The tag 'DataStoreChangedTrigger' does
>   not exist in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions

What's the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't added a reference to the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll or if you have you haven't referenced the Blend SDK 4 version of the this dll.

Comment: Thanks, I added the reference, where can I find the Blend SDK 4 version of it?

Comment: You only need the sdk if you don't have Blend installed. The sdk can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d&displaylang=en

Comment: @Brandon: When replying to a comment use the twitter style @username prefix as I have done here to a) indicate who you are replying to and b) and to cause that user to be notified of a response.

Comment: @cube1893: Are you using a Beta or RC version of Blend?

Comment: I have the sdk installed, still not working. It works till I try to build the solution. 
@AnthonyWJones I'm using RC version

Comment: @cube1893: You are building with Expression Blend or Visual Studio? If with Blend try Visual Studio.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones  Same thing happens in Visual Studio :-(

Comment: It turns out, that after restarting Visual Studio, it actually worked.